# TexStudio - не работает генерация PDF

Tags: latex, texstudio

После обновления fedora до 33 вдруг отказалась работать TexStudio. Точнее, при попытке запуска генерации PDF студия зависает, а если нажать на красный квадратик остановки процесса генерации PDF,  то в окошке лога вижу такие сообщения:

```
Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "WriteBot".tex
kpathsea: Running mktextfm larm1200
mkdir: cannot create directory '././app/texmf-var/fonts/tfm/lh': Read-only file system
mktextfm: mktexdir /app/texmf-var/fonts/tfm/lh/lh-t2a failed.
```

И что бы это значило?! Понятно, что студия пытается сгенерировать фонты, но где-то не хватает прав на запись. Но где ?

Две первые точки в сообщении сбивают с толку:

```
'././app/texmf-var/fonts/tfm/lh'
```

Что тут было **текущей** директорией?

Comment: `mktexdir /app/texmf-var/fonts/tfm/lh/lh-t2a failed` — вероятно, это и есть абсолютный путь, где «read only file system».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin - Но в корне ("/") нет каталога  "/app/"  :-(  Я подозреваю в чём дело. В старой версии у меня TexStudio была установлена из обычного rpm пакета, а в новой - из flatpack. При этом, старые настройки остались в "~". Так что я сейчас вообще не понимаю, что происходит.  Снёс и опять установил - вроде пока работает... :-(